# Amplitudes with external gauge bosons in Feynman gauge

Tags: standard-model, higgs

If I want to compute the tree amplitude for 2 particles annihilating into 2 gauge bosons, for example, $h h\to  Z Z$ in the Standard Model (SM), and I use  Feynman gauge, is it necessary to include diagrams with Goldstone bosons as external particles? I ask this because if I compute this amplitude using FeynArts + FormCalc it seems the result does not match the computation in the Unitary gauge with the same programs (FeynArts comes with an add on file for Unitary gauge in the SM).

Comment: For this type of calculations it is more convenient to use unitary gauge